# Hibernate Many to one mapping : Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have `Users` and a `Sport` table.

One user can have only one sport.

Multiple users can have same sport, so I created a join table `user_sport` with these two columns:

1. USER_ID
2. SPORT_ID

In my users entity, I have used the following :

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name = "USER_SPORT,
joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID")},
inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "SPORT_ID")})
private Sport sport;
```

Sport is an independent identity. I am able to persist sport.

On persisting user, i am getting following error :-

2021-07-22 20:21:20,600 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - Invalid column name

I have tried the following in Sport entity (although i think it should work without this), but it did not work :-

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "SPORT")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
@JsonIgnore
private Set<User> users;
```

Any quick help will he highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@prince you have declared mappedBy incorrectly. this should be the variable name annotated with @joinColumn.

Comment: Hi sir, I am using a join table named "USER_SPORTS", which contains mapping of user and sport. It has 2 columns - SPORT_ID and USER_ID.  Thats why I have used JoinTable instead of join column.

Comment: I also tried by adding a column of sport_id in user table and then constructing beans like following :-       
   SPORT ENTITY :-                                                                       
    OneToMany(mappedBy = "SPORT")
    JsonIgnore
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();

USER ENTITY :-
ManyToOne
 JoinColumn(name = “SPORT”_ID)
 private Sport sport;

By using this method, I am getting following error in bean creation :-

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: entity.User.SPORT in entity.Sport.users

Answer (score 0):

@Pilpo : I also tried by adding a column of sport_id in user table and then constructing beans like following :-

```
SPORT ENTITY :-                                                                       

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "SPORT")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<User> users = new HashSet<>();
```

USER ENTITY :-

```
@ManyToOne
 @JoinColumn(name = “SPORT”_ID)
 private Sport sport;
```

By using this method, I am getting following error in bean creation :-

org.hibernate.AnnotationException: mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: entity.User.SPORT in entity.Sport.users

Comment: It's sport, not SPORT. And  @JoinColumn(name = “SPORT_ID") instead of  @JoinColumn(name = “SPORT”_ID).

Comment: I did not get your point, can you please explain

Comment: Capital case is important :) => mappedBy = "sport"